# Does Kubernetes do network calls to containers on same host to reduce network traffic?

Tags: cloud, kubernetes, containers

Does Kubernetes prefer network requests to service containers on the same host - if available - over those on other hosts to reduce network calls across hosts in the cluster? Is this taken care of internally by Kubernetes - how do we tune it to do this?